# Java Vaadin session is changing after page reload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-session

In my [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow_(Java_API)) app, when I refresh the browser it gives me a new [`SpringVaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/current/com/vaadin/flow/spring/SpringVaadinSession.html) every 2nd or 3rd refresh.

I always print out the `SpringVaadinSession` when refreshing the page. This is the result:

```
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@18dd1208
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@64a5964b
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@64a5964b
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@52e6e25c
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@52e6e25c
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@52e6e25c
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@52e6e25c
com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringVaadinSession@52e6e25c
```

As you can see, I had 3 sessions in a few presses of f5 key.
This causes problems because some user data would be stored here.

I checked the lifetime of the session, which is 30 minutes.

I added the annotation [`@PreserveOnRefresh`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/current/com/vaadin/flow/router/PreserveOnRefresh.html). But it is still generating a new session after reload.

Example app:

```
@Route("/app")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class AppView extends AppLayout {
VaadinSession session = VaadinSession.getCurrent();
    public AppView() {
        System.out.println(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why press f5 at all? That's not idea behind a single page web application

Comment: @AndréSchild I'm just simply refreshing the page. I don't think it should generate a new session.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've added to the question.

Comment: what version are you using? 24.1+? If yes, try it with 24.0 to see if it's related to the "newly" introduced session clean up.

Comment: @Knoobie I switched, still not working.

Comment: If it's a Problem in Firefox, it could be similar to https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16833#issuecomment-1559015990

Comment: Just to make sure: did you check that the value is still stored in the session or did you just print out the  session without checking?

Comment: @Knoobie Yes, I always check. When the session changes, I can't reach the data stored in it anymore.

Comment: @Ronoo I tried with a simple V24 Spring Boot application, with and without `@PreserveOnRefresh`, and couldn't get the issue to reproduce.

Comment: If you can create a standalone reproducible example app, please do create a ticket in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/new/choose as this sounds like a bug.